# Queue Implementation in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I implemented a queue and various operations as shown below. Is there any other easy method to implement queue(Circular Queue) in Java?? Which is the easiest way to implement queue in java??

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class QueueImplement {

    LinkedList<Integer> list;
    String str;
    int num;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueImplement q = new QueueImplement();
    }

    public QueueImplement() {
        try {
            list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(ir);
            System.out.println("Enter number of elements : ");
            str = bf.readLine();
            if ((num = Integer.parseInt(str)) == 0) {
                System.out.println("You have entered either zero/null.");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter elements : ");
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                    str = bf.readLine();
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    list.add(n);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("First element :" + list.removeFirst());
            System.out.println("Last element :" + list.removeLast());
            System.out.println("Rest elements in the list :");
            while (!list.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print(list.remove() + "\t");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " is not a legal entry.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work for you? What are your requirements for this queue?

Comment: Do you have a *specific* question related to your code? Stack Overflow isn't for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You did not implement a queue, you just used a LinkedList (which already is a queue). You wrote a program that uses a queue.

Comment: Yes.. I implemented a queue using linked list. I just wanted to know is there any other easy way to implement a queue in java??

Comment: If this was a queue, you'd be able to do something like: `QueueImplement q = new QueueImplement(); q.enqueue(42);` As this is not the case, QueueImplement is not a queue. LinkedList is a queue, however.

Comment: use the Java Queue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) you used already implements [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list is a good way to go. Looking at your code though, I would suggest that most of it belongs in the main function. You've exercised queue like functionality in your constructor with a linked list, but to create a queue, you'd want to create a class that provides the interface and implementation of a queue.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayDeque` and `ArrayBlockingQueue` are implemented using Circular Array algorithm.